# How to use Titanium Backup to keep stuff through factory reset?

Tags: factory-reset, titanium-backup, cyanogenmod

I'm looking to factory reset my Nexus 4, which is currently running CyanogenMod 11 M7, because of an issue inside the ROM that requires a reset (Themes Provider crashing on every launch). I have Titanium Backup, and have created a backup. **How do I now back up (or put onto a computer and then return to the phone) the backup and restore it once I've resetted?** Or is there a better alternative to keep all my stuff through the reset?

Yes, I'm quite a noob at ROMs and rooting, before you say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TiBu* stores its backups in a folder on your SDCard (either the internal or the external, depends on what you have and how you've configured it). So you can simply copy that entire folder over to your PC before applying the factory-reset. Just check the root of your SDCard(s) for a folder named `TitaniumBackup`.

After the factory reset, the folder should still be there (unless your device is one of those including the card with the reset – hence the copy to PC, which in this case you now can simply copy back). Launch *TiBu*, and restore what you want to have restored.

One thing to keep in mind: I don't know what's causing your trouble, but restoring the entire backup completely might bring it back if the troublemaker was included there, so take care ;)